# Tangent spaces at different points on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

Why are tangent spaces on a general manifold associated to single points on the manifold? I've heard that it has to do with not being able to subtract/ add one point from/to another on a manifold (ignoring the concept of a connection at the moment), but I'm not sure I fully understand this - is it simply because, even if two points lie in the same coordinate patch the coordinate map will not be Cartesian (i.e. the identity map) in general, and so subtracting/adding their coordinate values will not correspond to subtracting/adding one point from/to another on the manifold?

Answer (score 0):

The tangent space can be thought of as a linear approximation to the manifold at a given point, this is the same as locally approximating a curve by its tangent line at a point.

We'll continue with the analogy of the tangent line to a curve. Imagine adding two vectors that lie along the same tangent line together, we get another vector which is also approximating the function in some sense at that point on the curve. However if I consider two tangent lines at different points in a curve then it won't be useful to try and add a vector from each together, I could add them componentwise if I wanted to but what would that give me? Potentially a new vector pointing off in a direction that bears no relation to the function at either of the two points from which we took tangent vectors. Hence if we did start adding vectors from the tangent spaces of a curve/ manifold then we would be ending up with objects that no longer represent anything about the original object we are studying, hence there is nothing very useful to gain by doing this.

I hope this helps clarify things.

Comment: Moreover, if the curve is not embedded in Euclidean space, there is no notion of components of vectors, and hence no notion of "adding vectors (in tangent spaces at different points) componentwise". (Given a chart, one can write down the components of a vector with respect to the coordinate basis $(\partial_{x^a})$, but the componentwise sum of vectors with different base points depends on the chart, i.e., is geometrically meaningless.)

Comment: @EHH "*I could add them component wise if I wanted to but what would that give me? Potentially a new vector pointing off in a direction that bears no relation to the function at either of the two points from which we took tangent vectors.*" ... Is this because adding coordinates (vector components) in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ will not correspond to adding points on the manifold (or vectors in the tangent space) because the coordinate map will be, in general, be non-trivial?

Comment: I was considering the simple example where the curve is embedded in euclidean space, assume we try adding two vectors together from different tangent spaces. Imagine a bell shaped curve, then I can add a vector from the tangent of a point on the right hand side of the summit to a vector from a tangent space on the left hand side of the summit (assuming the trivial charts) and get a vector that points straight up! But this vector isn't from any tangent line along the bell shaped curve. So even when we try and add component wise we don't get anything meaningful out.

Comment: In the bell shaped curve example, the vector pointing straight up is what I meant by saying that we can end up with a vector pointing in a direction that bears no relation to our original object (curve here) since the curve has no tangent space in that direction.